# Practice for MQ upgrade

Tags: migration, upgrade, ibm-mq

I am working on a project of upgrading MQ 8 to MQ9.

- QM A is existing MQ8, in use, connecting to remote QM X
- I created new v9 QM, also named A, as it's supposed to replace the old A

Problem is, old QM A will exist for months, as there are a few projects running on it, and I need to test the MQ objects ( queues / channels ) on new QM A

Question is, what's the best practice for this case? new QM has same name with old QM

Answer (score 0):

Backup the configuration from QMA (v8) and load it the new QMA (v9) in a test environment. Test the critical message flow paths, and then plan for a cutover in production.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the advice